# add mouse listeners to drop target

Tags: java, swing, jtable, drag-and-drop

```
DefaultTableModel modeltable = new DefaultTableModel(8,8);

table = new JTable(modeltable);
table.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder (Color.blue, 2));

int height = table.getRowHeight();
table.setRowHeight(height=50);

table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
table.setDragEnabled(true);

le1.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

panel.add(table);
panel.setSize(400,400);

    DnDListener dndListener = new DnDListener();
    DragSource dragSource = new DragSource();
    DropTarget dropTarget1 = new DropTarget(table, dndListener);

   DragGestureRecognizer dragRecognizer2 = dragSource.
            createDefaultDragGestureRecognizer(option1, 
          DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY, dndListener);
   DragGestureRecognizer dragRecognizer3 = dragSource.
            createDefaultDragGestureRecognizer(option2, 
            DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY, dndListener);


}
}
```

i have a problem with adding mouse listeners to "table" which is drop target, to accept drop component wherever it drops from the mouse. in this code when component drops in to a drop target it always goes to a default position. i cant customize the position on drop target. please someone help me with this.
thanks in advance

Comment: unrelated: sizing/positioning of component's is the exclusive task of a LayoutManager, so setSize is _never_ used (and has no effect except in the horror scenario of null layout, _dont-dont-dont_ :)

Answer (score 5):

Those listeners are far too low-level. The appropriate approach for implementing dnd is to implement a custom TransferHandler and set that custom handler to your table.

```
 public class MyTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {

    public boolean canImport(TransferHandler.TransferSupport info) {
        // we only import Strings
        if (!info.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
            return false;
        }

        JTable.DropLocation dl = (JTable.DropLocation)info.getDropLocation();
        // ... your code to decide whether the data can be dropped based on location 
    }

    public boolean importData(TransferHandler.TransferSupport info) {
        if (!info.isDrop()) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check for String flavor
        if (!info.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
            displayDropLocation("Table doesn't accept a drop of this type.");
            return false;
        }

        JTable.DropLocation dl = (JTable.DropLocation)info.getDropLocation();
        // ... your code to handle the drop
   }

}

// usage
myTable.setTransferHandler(new MyTransferHandler());
```

For details, see the example in the online tutorial linked to in the Swing tag description, namely the [chapter Drag and Drop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html) The code snippet above is c&p'ed from the BasicDnD example.